# How can I opening a directory from the terminal in a new session?

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files, pantheon-terminal

Coming from Mac OS, in terminal I am able to use `open .` in terminal which will open a directory.

I am able to semi replicate this with `pantheon-files .`, but this returns

```
[INFO 21:33:37.889767] Application.vala:155: Files version: 0.2.4
[INFO 21:33:37.889846] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.19.0-33-generic
[WARNING 21:33:37.894015] Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-0hpFTi9zyT: Connection refused
[INFO 21:33:37.930317] Application.vala:85: Report any issues/bugs you might find to http://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files
```

To get round the above issue I use `pantheon-files . > /dev/null`. However, the command is still running in my terminal session and when I close it in terminal it closes the window I have just opened.

My question, can I open a directory from terminal without leaving the session open?

Comment: what do you mean "without leaving the session open"?

Comment: btw the message is common, but not an error: =)

Comment: @Ravan: I used the word session in the sense of `pantheon-files` running. If that makes sense. So, to continue to use terminal after running the command I would need to hit `ctrl` + `c`.

Comment: Well, see @DanielFore answer, hope it solve :)

Comment: I am sure still you need to use Ctrl+c to use terminal after running the command even after using `xdg-open .` Isn't it?

Comment: See my edit @Nigel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `xdg-open .` is what you're looking for. I'm able to close Terminal without quitting Files.

The other Terminal output can be ignored

Comment: Cheer Daniel. I have managed to do the following to replicate the functionality.

Answer (score 3):

To detcach a program from a terminal simply run the command with a `&` at the end like this:

```
pantheon-files . &
```

Then simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and the terminal will close, leaving the program running.

This works for anything - even when `xdg-open` does not.

Answer (score 1):

To open file/folder from terminal:

1. `pantheon-files /path`

   Example: `pantheon-files /home/ravan/Downloads`
2. `xdg-open /path`

   Example: `xdg-open /home/ravan/Downloads`

**EDIT** 1:

> . (dot) represents the current working directory;
>
> .. (dot dot) represent the directory one level above the current working directory, often referred to as the parent directory.

**EDIT 2**:
 To clarify [comment](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3073/opening-a-directory-from-terminal#comment5419_3073)-

To use terminal after running the command `xdg-open /path` :

Run the command instead of the previous one:

```
xdg-open /path ; sleep 1
```

Here it will be `xdg-open . ; sleep 1`

To close terminal automatically:

```
xdg-open /path ; exit
```

Here it would be : `xdg-open . ; exit`

Answer (score 0):

I've created a bash alias to use the `xdg-open .` command like the MacOs `open .` ignoring the command output. You can place the alias at your `.bash_profile` to make it persistent.

```
alias open='xdg-open &> /dev/null'
```